# MtFrame GoBackToAsync pop or navigate back to Nth page without loading N-1 pages

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, windows-phone, winrt-xaml, mytoolkit

I am using [MyToolkit](http://mytoolkit.codeplex.com) [MtFrame](https://mytoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MtFrame) class for paging in my WinRT app. I am wondering if there is a way to navigate back to Nth page on the stack without loading intermediate pages.

Lets says, here is how my pages stack looks like:

```
Page 1 -> Page 2 -> Page 3 -> Page 4 -> Page 5 -> Page 6
```

Now from "Page 6" if I call `MtFrame.GoBackToAsync(Page 2)`, it pops pages 3-5 and calling its `OnNavigatedTo` event.

Is there any way I can skip loading of pages 3-5 or alteast make it not call the `OnNavigatedTo` event for those pages?

Comment: Have you tried the RemovePageFromStackAt method to remove unwanted pages before navigation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the way `GoBackToAsync` is currently implemented. But you could first remove the pages using `RemovePageFromStackAt` and then only call `GoBackAsync`:

Assuming you are on page 6 and want to go to page 2, use this code:

```
frame.RemovePageFromStackAt(Page5);
frame.RemovePageFromStackAt(Page4);
frame.RemovePageFromStackAt(Page3);
await frame.GoBackAsync();
```

Because you removed the pages 3-5 beforehand, `GoBackAsync` jumps from page 6 to page 2...

But keep in mind: This way the pages are removed forever and forward navigation is broken and should therefore be disabled...

The only clean solution is to implement `GoBackToAsync` so that it not only calls `GoBackAsync` multiple times... Please create an issue on the codeplex project for that.

The generic code from @Vasanth:

```
while (currentView.Frame.PreviousPage != desiredPage) 
{ 
    currentView.Frame.RemovePageFromStackAt(currentView.Frame.CurrentIndex - 1); 
}
```

**Update:** In MyToolkit v2.3.29 you can use `GoBackToAsync`, the problem is now fixed...

Comment: Thanks @Rico, it worked!, just incase if someone needs the logic to be dynamic, below is what I did:

while (currentView.Frame.PreviousPage != desiredPage)
{
currentView.Frame.RemovePageFromStackAt(currentView.Frame.CurrentIndex - 1);
}

Comment: Thx, but you know, this is not a good solution because it completely removes the pages and not only navigates back... forward navigation will be broken.

Comment: As soon as I have time I will reimplement the `GoBackToAsync` method so that it works correctly.